# How to install Kotlin in Eclipse for Android Development?

Tags: android, eclipse, kotlin

I just tried searching on Google how to do it but still I could not find a comprehensive step by step instruction on how to do this?

Comment: I suggest to move to Android Stuido. ADT plugin for Eclipse is no longer in active development so at some point you will have to migrate to AS. Also, for the same reason, I don't expect much focus on integration for Kotlin + Eclipse + Android.

Comment: Yeah now I am using Android Studio.

Comment: I find Eclipse much more snappy and productive than IntelliJ (base of Android Studio), hence I am still looking for a good answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find some information about [installing the kotlin-eclipse plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-eclipse).

As suggested in this beautiful blog post [The Adventurous Developer’s Guide to JVM languages](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/the-adventurous-developers-guide-to-jvm-languages-kotlin/) – Kotlin (it's worth reading it) you can always directly ask to [kotlin community](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/Kotlin/Welcome)

Comment: Since Android studio has moved to Intellij, it doesn't make sense to try to do this in Eclipse does it?

Answer (score 0):

**Install kotlin using the Software Development Kit (SDK) manager
And Use Android Studio**

Type the following command to install sdk:

```
$ wget -O sdk.install.sh "https://get.sdkman.io"
$ vi sdk.install.sh
$ bash sdk.install.sh
```

Type the following commands to install kotlin:

```
$ source ~/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh
$ sdk install kotlin
```

**Install JDK**

Type the following command :

```
$ sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jre-headless
```

Write your first kotlin program

```
Create a file called hello.kt:
$ vi hello.kt
```

Append the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("Hello, World!")
}
```

Save and close the file. Compile your app into jar:

```
$ kotlinc hello.kt -include-runtime -d hello.jar
```

Run your app:

```
$ java -jar hello.jar
```

Enjoy !